# Oracle SQL: How to insert row based on criteria?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I’ve a table Applicant:

| ID | Received |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | food |
| 1 | rent assistance |
| 1 | bus ticket |
| 2 | food |
| 2 | rent assistance |
| 3 | food |
| 4 | bus ticket |
| 5 | null |

As you can see, I've an Applicant table where applicant has received varying number of benefits. But now I need to check this candidate table and ensure all applicant gets all 3 benefits: food, rent assistance, and a bus ticket. An applicant also cannot receive this benefits twice. How to achieve this in oracle sql?

Note: I've Benefits table where benefits are mapped to a unique id (food = 100, rent assistance = 101, bus ticket = 102). I've written the name instead of a number for readability.

I looked various statements like MERGE and EXISTS, but couldn't see how this'd apply to my case.

Comment: Table structures???  Have you tried anything?  Sample input?  Expected output?

Comment: I've included table structure for Applicant. input would be just (id, <benefit_type>) where benefit doesn't exist. Expected output would be all applicants with all benefits. In this case, 5 applicants times 3 benefits = 15 rows.

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055) and how to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `MERGE` statement and a `PARTITION`ed `OUTER JOIN`:

```sql
MERGE INTO applicant dst
USING (
  WITH benefits (benefit) AS (
    SELECT 'food'            FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'rent assistance' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'bus ticket'      FROM DUAL
  )
  SELECT a.ROWID AS rid,
         a.pID,
         b.benefit
  FROM   benefits b
         LEFT OUTER JOIN applicant a
         PARTITION BY (a.pID)
         ON (a.received = b.benefit)
) src
ON (src.rid = dst.ROWID)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (pID, Received) VALUES (src.pID, src.benefit);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE applicant (pID, Received) AS
SELECT 1, 'food' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'rent assistance' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'bus ticket' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'food' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'rent assistance' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'food' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'bus ticket' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, null FROM DUAL;
```

Then, after the `MERGE`, the table contains:

| PID | RECEIVED |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | food |
| 1 | rent assistance |
| 1 | bus ticket |
| 2 | food |
| 2 | rent assistance |
| 3 | food |
| 4 | bus ticket |
| 5 | (null) |
| 2 | bus ticket |
| 3 | bus ticket |
| 3 | rent assistance |
| 4 | food |
| 4 | rent assistance |
| 5 | bus ticket |
| 5 | food |
| 5 | rent assistance |

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f5e86/1)